Introducing Empty Pages leads to "MiKTeX Ghostscript GPL 9.25 Unrecover Error, exit code 1 "but Process Exits normally
I think I have finally been able to replicate the Issue I have been facing.
For my Master Thesis, I want to have a Preface which I want numbered with Roman Numerals and to include things like the TOC, Abbreviations and so on.
I also only want it to be on odd pages, so it's directly visible when opening the Thesis and more or less only the right side of a double page is used, if you understand what I mean by that.
Shouldn't be too hard, I thought, the way I usually did it was the following:
Text
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
More Text

This used to work fine.
But now that I started writing my Master Thesis, I noticed that when I do this, upon compiling I get the short notice "MikTeX Ghostscript GPL 9.25: Unrecoverable Error, exit code 1. Then it tells me "Process Exited normally" and the whole thing compiles.
But this seems to cause further issues down that road that I am now unable to solve, therefore I need to solve this error first.
Originally I thought it was linked to hyperref and auto-pst-pdf, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Then I thought it might be related to me switching the numbering between the Preface and the main text from Roman to Arabic, but that shouldn't be the reason either.
To me, it seems like it's related to empty pages, so I have typed out a MWE that can showcase the error in 3 Ways.
The Error also appears irregardless of wether it is infront of changing the numbering from Roman to Arabic or after.
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,bibliography=totocnumbered,listof=totocnumbered, onehalfspacing]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[crop=off, runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,autooneside=false,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[linktocpage=true]{hyperref}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\tolerance=500
\geometry{a4paper, top=27mm, left=30mm, right=20mm, bottom=25mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}
\hypersetup{unicode=false, pdftoolbar=true, pdfmenubar=true, pdffitwindow=false, pdfstartview={Fit},
    pdftitle={Minimal Working Example},
    pdfauthor={Paul},
    pdfsubject={Bugfixes},
    pdfcreator={pdfTeX \the\pdftexversion.\pdftexrevision},
    pdfproducer={Paul},
    pdfkeywords={},
    pdfnewwindow=true,
    colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,filecolor=magenta,urlcolor=black}
\pdfinfo{/CreationDate (D:20241022)}

\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\mdseries}
\rohead{\leftmark}
\rofoot{\thepage}
\lehead{\leftmark}
\lefoot{\thepage}

\AtBeginDocument{
    \ifpdf\else
        \@ifpackageloaded{preview}{
            \ifPreview
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/firstpage}[hyperref]
                \RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[hyperref]
            \fi
        }{}
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\Roman{section}}
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{document}

THIS IS A TITLEPAGE

%Error disappears if all 4 below are removed. If only the first 3 lines are removed Error still appear.
\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{\fill}
\newpage
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}

This is the real document.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[]{Benzene}
    \caption{The Hydrocarbon Benzene}
    \label{Benzene}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{Benzene} shows the Hydrocarbon Benzene.


\end{document}

I have also uploaded the 3 different examples including logfiles to wetransfer (if there is a better, more permanent upload solution I'd be willing to do that as well).
https://we.tl/t-ucsMXjlRPG
Thank you again for all your help!

try if it works if you add \RemoveFromHook{shipout/lastpage}[bookmark] to the fixes.

@UlrikeFischer it actually works. However, now, when adding a Table of Contents with \tableofcontents, I again get the GPL Ghostscript Error. Do I need a seperate MWE to show this or is this easy to fix?

I can't reproduce that. And with auto-pst-pdf there is normally never an easy fix. One always need an example.

@UlrikeFischer thank you for all your help. I managed to "fix" the last Ghostscript Error I was facing when including \tableofcontents by simply copying and pasting EVERYTHING from one document into a fresh one and then compiling. I can't tell you why it worked but I guess sometimes it is like that.
